# Are there reactive state libraries like Mobx for Python?

Tags: python, webserver, reactive-programming, messaging, state-management

I'm looking for reactive state libraries like [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) for Python, i.e. on server-side rather than client-side of a web application.

Mobx is similar to classic reactive libraries like [RxPY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY), but has a different focus: It is not so much avout the low-level event dispatching, but reacting on data changes, recalculating derived values (but only those affected, and being lazy on non-observed dependent values). And Mobx determines dependencies of calculated values automatically.

Also, the [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) framework has such functionality built-in, with an even better syntax, with the upside (as well as downside) by being closely tied to the framework.

Alas, both are JavaScript and targeted at client-side / user interface.

So my specific questions are:

- Are there similar reactive state libraries for Python?
- Do these provide integration for storing/observing data in files?

  - (This would essentially be an inotify-based build system, but more fine-grained and more flexible.)
- Do these provide integration with relational databases?

  - (Yes, there is a conceptual gap to be bridged, and it probably works only as long a single server instance accesses the database. It would still be very useful for wide range of applications.)
- Do these provide integration with webserver frameworks?

  - (i.e. received HTTP requests trigger state changed and reclaculations, some calculated values are JSON structures which are observed by the client through web sockets, long polling or messaging systems.)

Comment: May be this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY is for you.

Comment: @RichardRublev I adjusted my question to make it more clear that classic reactive libraries such as RxPY are *not* what I'm looking for (unless they are more similar to Mobx state management than what can be seen from their documentation.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did one. It's called MoPyX. It's toolkit independent so you can just observe objects. But is geared towards UIs.

See: https://github.com/germaniumhq/mopyx

PySide2 demo: https://github.com/germaniumhq/mopyx-sample